# Page speed issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

While testing page loading time on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=aishwat.com it says

```
Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
```

and lists down few javascripts (which you may look at [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=aishwat.com) provided)

Now, I am using these as base scripts *angular.min.js, angular-animate.min.js, angular-aria.min.js, angular-material.min.js*
And they need to be loaded in this particular order (one can't load angular animate before angular)

The question is **how to make them non blocking ?**

I have already kept them outside head block

**Source code** : https://github.com/aishwat/aishwat.com/blob/develop/public/index.html

Plz have a look at source page

Comment: If you click on the error you will [land on this page telling you how](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS).

Comment: ya it advises to make them inline or async/defer . I cant make them inline, because they are big and i cant make them async/defer because then it doesn't maintain loading order

Comment: Use `defer` instead of `async` to maintain your order

Comment: See the answer below, just move them to where they're non blocking.

Comment: @A1rPun vl give it a try, give me 2 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PageSpeed insight site has a good documentation [what you can do](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) to prevent it.

To make your javascript non-blocking you can add the `async` or `defer` attributes to your script tags. To maintain the order it is recommended to use `defer`.

```
<script defer src="my.js">
```

I see your `<script>` tags are outside of your `<body>`, this is not valid HTML so I recommend putting them back at the head or somewhere in your body.

Comment: ya this does it , i thought async and defer are same and it wont maintain order, my bad. Anyways but any similar thing for css delivery too ? see this now https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=aishwat.com&tab=mobile

Comment: @aishwatsingh Good question, there isn't such thing as `async` or `defer` for CSS files but [this article](http://www.giftofspeed.com/defer-loading-css/) has some good suggestions.

Comment: one more issue, as u see i was having a fallback approach like
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js" defer></script>
<script>
window.angular || document.write('<script src="javascripts/angular.min.js" defer>\x3C/script>')
</script>
`
now it loads both offline and cdn version

Comment: tried this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js" defer></script>
<script defer>
window.angular || document.write('<script src="javascripts/angular.min.js" defer>\x3C/script>')
</script>`
but it's still loading local script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627789/html-script-loading-with-fallback-approach-and-differ