# html script loading with fallback approach and differ

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a script fallback approach like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js" defer></script>
<script defer>
window.angular || document.write('<script src="javascripts/angular.min.js" defer>\x3C/script>')
</script>
```

without differ tag , it loads only cdn version and not local one, but after putting differ tag , it loads both.

Any idea how to resolve this , original source https://github.com/aishwat/aishwat.com/blob/develop/public/index.html

Comment: The `defer` & `async` attributes will not work with [`scripts that don't have the src attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). You could include that 1 line in a file a load it with defer.